# "Not found" condition being recognized as a type/variable?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increaseSomeOfferPricesFunction(IN theOffererID INTEGER, IN numOfferIncreases INTEGER) RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN    
DECLARE a INTEGER;    
DECLARE b INTEGER;    
DECLARE c DATE;    
DECLARE d INTEGER = 0;
DECLARE NotFound CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';
```

When I try to create this stored function, I get the error CONTEXT:  invalid type name "CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000'"

I'm confused as to why this is happening, as I'm almost positive the syntax is correct.

Comment: Does this exist in Postgresql?  It's in MySql.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `declare` starts a _block_ where multiple variables are [defined](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/), there is no need to start a new declare block for each variable. One block for all of them is enough.

Comment: "*I'm almost positive the syntax is correct.*" - where in the [PL/pgSQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) did you find that?

Comment: There is no need to declare "not found", [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) the SQLSTATE `02000` is available in the pre-defined condition `no_data`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this was taught in my lecture, I guessed I missed the part where he says it's not pgsql.

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL/PSM language (it is used by MySQL or DB2) - It is not PL/pgSQL. MySQL uses different language for stored procedures than Postgres does.

PL/pgSQL requires variable declaration before `BEGIN` keyword. Second, PL/pgSQL doesn't support conditions declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increaseSomeOfferPricesFunction(IN theOffererID INTEGER, 
                                                          IN numOfferIncreases INTEGER) 
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
  a INTEGER;    
  b INTEGER;    
  c DATE;    
  d INTEGER = 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
  IF NOT FOUND THEN ...
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```